# Single page grails application, render templates deferred

Tags: grails, backbone.js, marionette

I have a grails application with bootstrap and marionette.
The whole application is a single page application.

The concept worked very well in the beginning. But now I have lots of pages and the first load takes very long.

I have one file where all the templates are rendered like:

```
<g:render template="/page/workflow"/>
```

I load about 150 templates in this file

Is it possible that I render only the first necessary templates for the start page and after displaying the start page I want to render all the rest of the pages in background.
Is this somehow possible?

Comment: It is not only loading but also compiling the templates. What templating engine do you use? Show us how you handle your templates.  If you already use the asset pipeline you could use the handlebars-asset-plugin to precompile your templates.

Comment: Hi, I found out that I had another problem with my application. This rendering happens only on the first start of my application after restarting the tomcat. My real problem was that I had too much javascript files to load. Now I merge the JS files into one file and the reload works fine now